# Use \left( and \right) in mhchem

Tags: delimiters, mhchem

When I try to use the `\left(` and `\right)` commands in a chemistry equation, using `mhchem`, I get multiple errors. It is also not possible to use `\bigl(` or similar.

For example, the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
    \[\ce{Zn/Zn^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right) // Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}\]
\end{document}
```

Gives these errors:

- line 4: Missing delimiter (. inserted). ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Missing \right. inserted. ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Missing \endgroup inserted. ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Missing \endgroup inserted. ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Missing delimiter (. inserted). ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Extra \right. ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Missing delimiter (. inserted). ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Missing \right. inserted. ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Missing $ inserted. ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Display math should end with $$. ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Missing delimiter (. inserted). ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Extra \right. ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Extra \endgroup. ...Pb^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}
- line 4: Bad math environment delimiter. ...^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}]
- line 4: \begin{document} ended by \end{equation*}. ...^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}]
- line 4: Missing $ inserted. ...^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}]
- line 4: Display math should end with $$. ...^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}]
- line 4: Extra \endgroup. ...^{2+} \left(c = 1\frac{mol}{l}\right)/Pb}]

If I were to write the same code without a `mhchem` equation, I would get no error.

Is there any workaround or another way to use parentheses that automatically scale in `mhchem`?

Comment: Please, can you add  full example?

Comment: @Sebastiano I added more information

Comment: Don't tell me you really use `\left( … \right)`  for such a content as 1!

Comment: The third one is not an error but a warning and is completely unrelated with your question… Can you give a use case where you actually would want scaled delimiters _within_ a chemical formula?

Comment: What does "giving the concentration in a fraction" refer to in the context of a reaction equation? Do you refer to stochiometric numbers/factors such as 1/2 O2? Using `\ce{1/2 O2}` or `\ce{(1/2) O2}` should be sufficient for that.

Comment: @leandriis I added more information to the question

Comment: Some more background information on the context would be useful. Where exactly do you want to show the concentration? Inside of the text or in some kind of mathematical equation,...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument of `\ce` is processed in a quite complicated fashion and math mode is not in effect. This works, see page 9 of the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\[
\ce{
  Zn/Zn^{2+} $\Big($ c = 1\frac{mol}{l} $\Big)$
  // Pb^{2+} $\Big($ c = 1\frac{mol}{l} $\Big)$/Pb
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `c` should be in italic. As most of the equation is math and not chemistry, I would suggest just putting `Zn` etc. into `\ce` and leaving the rest outside.

Answer (score 6):

I am still not quite sure in which context you want to display the concentration of Pb2+ ions (inside of the text or of a mathematical equation or...). Nevertheless, here are some options :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage{siunitx} % provides the SI command to typeset number and their units
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{units} % Provides the \Molar unit
\begin{document}

\ce{Pb^{2+}} \(\left(c = \SI{1}{\mol\per\liter}\right)\)
  
\[ \ce{Pb^{2+}} \left(c = \SI{1}{\mol\per\liter}\right) \]


\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\ce{Pb^{2+}} \((c = \SI{1}{\mol\per\liter})\)

\sisetup{per-mode=reciprocal}
\ce{Pb^{2+}} \((c = \SI{1}{\mol\per\liter})\)

\ce{Pb^{2+}} \((c = \SI{1}{\Molar})\)

\end{document}
```